# Call retries were exceeded error while archiving react-native application in x code

Tags: node.js, xcode, react-native, mobile

I'm trying to archive my react native application on xcode but I keep getting the following error

```
error node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js: Call retries were exceeded.

Error: Call retries were exceeded

    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/Users/me/Desktop/app/reactnative_mobile/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:193:21)

    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/Users/me/Desktop/app/reactnative_mobile/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/ChildProcessWorker.js:274:12)

    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

I've been trying to debug this for the past few days so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to remove jest-worker from node modules (as i'm not using it). I've also tried increasing the available memory for Node.js.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.